# Rake task is not getting executed in rails controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake-task

I am trying to call rake task in one of my methods of controller. The action is getting executed the method is also getting redirected but my rake task is not working. I have tried everything system, backticks, calling another model method etc. But its not at all working. And its happening only in production in development it works fine. I have no clue what is wrong. Thanks in advance.

```
`rake maintenance:sidekiq:print`
```

or

```
system('rake maintenance:sidekiq:print')
```

Comment: Can you show us how you call `rake task`, your task implementation and your action implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you are calling the task, but there are couple of ways

```
system "rake task_name"
```

Else you can do something like

```
require 'rake'
Rake::Task["task_name"].invoke
```

It works for me .

Comment: First one works in development but not in production and second one is through error 'Don't know how to build task 'maintenance:sidekiq:stop' when i did this ```Rake::Task["maintenance:sidekiq:stop"].invoke```

Comment: @ShilpiAgrawal issue is not with the code issue is how you setup sidekiq for the code . First one will work in every move provided you have set up everything correctly.